# How can I create a new Azure CDN using C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, azure

I have a tool in C# creating cloud service, storage and service bus. I need to create a new Azure CDN as well.

I couldn't find any proper document on how to programmatically create a new CDN, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure CDN management isn't available yet via REST API, PowerShell or .NET Management Libraries, but it is [planned](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/3573409-enable-cdn-endpoint-management-using-the-rest-api).